# Associate points with polygon QGIS 2.2

Tags: raster, polygon, point, qgis-2, polygonize

I want to associate a point layer with a polygon layer so that I can do zonal statistics. In the image below, the polygon layer represents roughly the metro area of a certain city. The point represents the city. The polygon is a result of a polygonized process from a raster image. I want to use these new polygons as buffers to analyze the original raster. However, I need a way to associate the city points with the surrounding polygons.

In other words, I want to find zonal statistics for each city ("oecdminusa") using the corresponding metro polyon ("polygontest"). When I ran zonal stats the first time, it simply named each of the polygons in "polygontest" as 1,2,3,4 etc. How do I make it correspond with the appropriate city?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join points and ploygons by location and continue your analysis with the join result. The join will append point attributes to the polygons inside which the points are located. Polygons which do not contain any points will have NULL values.

Comment: That did exactly what I needed it to. I now have attributes for the metro areas aligned with the point data. Thank you.